# How can I limit an operation in imagemagick to just the lower half of the picture?

Tags: imagemagick

Starting with the command below, I would like to apply `-fill red` on the top half of the picture and `-fill green` on the bottom half.

(I know I could break up the picture, and reassemble it after the two `-fill` operations, but as a member of this site I should not sink that low.)

```
convert 05.png -fuzz 20% -fill green -opaque white gr.05.png
```

Second question, can I chain two (or more) transforms into a single `convert` command?

Comment: hm, while you *can* run `convert` on a UNIXoid operating system, this strikes me as very operating system-independent question. Maybe superuser.com has more imagemagick experts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to do that is via the [`-region geometry`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#region) option. You set a region, apply the desired operations, when finished you unset the region; you then set another region, apply other operations and when finished you unset that region too and so on...  e.g. with an image size of `800x600` you'd run:

```
convert input.jpg \
-fuzz 20% \
-region '800x300+0+0' -fill green -opaque white +region \
-region '800x300+0+300' -fill red -opaque white +region \
output.jpg
```

To avoid hardcoding the image width/height... in this case the geometry could also be written as `100x50%` (meaning `100%` of width and `50%` of height) and instead of using offsets you prepend `-gravity` to `-region` so as to start from top or bottom:

```
convert input.jpg \
-fuzz 20% \
-gravity North -region '100x50%' -fill green -opaque white \
+region \
-gravity South -region '100x50%' -fill red -opaque white \
+region \
output.jpg
```

You can chain several commands e.g. you could add to the above `-resize` or `-crop` etc... and you also have the so called [*image stack*](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry):

> It permits you to work on an image or image sequence in isolation and
> subsequently introduce the results back into the command-line. The
> image stack is delineated with parenthesis. Image operators only
> affect images in the current stack.